# Access VBA for command button

Tags: vba

when I debug in the editor I don't get syntax errors, but when I click the button on my form nothing happens. Trying to add 6 months to the field with a click of the button.  Does anyone know if this code is wrong or incomplete?

```
Private Sub Ctl6mosBtn_Click()
    EXPIRATIONDATE = [AUTO POLICIES.EFFECTIVE DATE] = DateAdd("m", 6, EXPIRATIONDATE)
End Sub
```

Thanks for you any insight
Frank

I have two fields on my form

1-AUTO POLICIES.EFFECTIVE DATE which is the effective date of a policy.
2-EXPIRATIONDATE which is the expiration date of the policy.

I have a button labeled 6 Mos which when clicked should fill the EXPIRATIONDATE 6 months after the Effective Date. Nothing happens, no errors, fields doesn't fill!